# How do I correct fixed positioning for a sidebar in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, positioning

I have following HTML in my webpage where I want to keep the sidebar fixed on the left side.It works fine in the Chrome but Firfox isn't displaying the sidebar as fixed :

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- Logo -->
        <div >
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
            <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#target1" >About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#target2" >Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#target3" >Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#target4" >Contact</a></li>
                    
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                       
</div>
```

---

the CSS for above code is :

---

```
#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 3em 1.35em 1em 1.15em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12em; 
    background: #364050 ;
    box-shadow: inset -0.1em 0em 0.35em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

please suggest me some solution so that the sidebar will remain fixed in Firefox.

Comment: seems to work good for me. i would also add left:0; to your css

Comment: Can you describe what happens in Firefox? Even better, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and show us. Also, you might want to try adding `left: 0;` to `#sidebar`

Comment: Can't see anything wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/sH4ZX/

Comment: @Luke,the link has been added to the question.actually one more selector is applying style to the sidebar that only contains `left:0`.I have tried adding `position : fixed`to that selector but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your body css tags, the metas, and anything that could affect to that div. Maybe there is another css rule overwriting that 'position'
Also, if you have css3 tags or errors in the body css, for example, `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` that could make fixed position break in Firefox.

Comment: I also had issues with `backface-visiblity: hidden` on the `<body>` causing all `position: fixed` elements to break. Removing that fixed the issue in Firefox.

Comment: +1 for backface-visibility from @shshaw.
Even though I don't know why it works but you save my life. ;)

Comment: seems css `filter: ...` will also cause `position: fixed` not to work on firefox...

Comment: I had `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { :root { filter: invert(); } }` which was breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` on the current element or any parent will cause position fixed break on Firefox. Remove it or find another way to not to use filter directly

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to make some changes in you css
try this css

```
#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px; 
    background: #364050 ;
    box-shadow: inset -0.1em 0em 0.35em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

i do not prefer to use em for element dimensions it should be in px you can use em foe font size etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    padding: 3em 1.35em 1em 1.15em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12em; 
    background: #364050 ;
    box-shadow: inset -0.1em 0em 0.35em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine on google chrome but on firefox, You need to Add The properties (Top ,Bottom ,Left,Right ) for the fixed div
like this

```
       top : 0;
```